# Docker for Windows REST API - enable CROSS

Tags: javascript, rest, docker, electron

Right now I'm working on a small GUI for using docker. I'm using electron.js and Vue.js for this. Since desktop applications written in electron are embedded Chrome apps, I have a problem when I try to send request to docker REST API:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:2375/containers/json.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:9080' is therefore not allowed access
```

Nothing unusual, its behaving like it should since its a browser.

The real question is how to enable CROSS request to docker REST API ?

I'm using version 17.03.0-ce

Comment: I believe this depends on what you're running in your Docker container. Whatever is in the container would need to add that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. For instance, you can add [this for an nginx server in a docker container](https://gist.github.com/michiel/1064640).

Answer (score 1):

The docker daemon provides options to enable CORS headers for the REST API.
When starting the daemon, try setting the flags `--api-enable-cors` and `--api-cors-header`, for instance:

```
sudo dockerd --api-enable-cors --api-cors-header=http://localhost:9080
```

The REST API should then provide the necessary headers. Interestingly, `--api-enable-cors` is not documented in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/), but nonetheless required.